# ImportError: No module named 'Kernel'

Tags: python, window, kernel, chatbot, aiml

I'm using windows 10 and working on a chatbot project and use aiml integrated with python
I got this error

```
import aiml
File"C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\aiml\__init__.py", line 4, in <module>  
from Kernel import Kernel  
ImportError: No module named 'Kernel'
```

when running the integration code here

```
 import aiml

    # Create the kernel and learn AIML files 
      kernel = aiml.Kernel() 
      kernel.learn("std-startup.xml") 
      kernel.respond("load aiml b")    
    # Press CTRL-C to break this loop while True:
      print (kernel.respond(raw_input("Enter your message >> ")))
```

and my aiml directory contains the file__init__.py
here's it's content

```
__all__ = []

# The Kernel class is the only class most implementations should need. 
  from Kernel import Kernel
```

also file Kernel exists .. so what is the problem ?

Comment: You can use python --version to check the default python version. You can refer this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/43954498/6521116) for more.

Answer (score 3):

I've had a look at the code and tested it locally, and the `aiml` module seemingly does not currently support Python 3, but loads perfectly fine in Python 2.7.

Install [Python 2.7](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-2710/) and things should work a lot better for you.

Answer (score 3):

Try to install python-aiml

```
  pip install python-aiml
```

It is an updated version and therefore it should work fine.