# Am trying to built a chat bot using aiml with python

Tags: python, module, aiml

```
import aiml
import os
kernel = aiml.kernel()
if os.path.isfile("bot_brain.brn"):
    kernel.bootstrap(brainFile = "bot_brain.brn")
else:
    kernel.bootstrap(learnFiles = "std-startup.xml", commands = "load aiml b")
    kernel.savebrain("bot_brain.brn")
while True:
    print kernel.respond(raw_input("Enter Your Message")).strip()
aiml.kernel()
```

It is throwing an error like

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "**init**.py", line 3, in 
    kernel = aiml.kernel()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'kernel'

Comment: refer this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33971517/6521116), this may helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

aiml.kernel() should be aiml.Kernel()

Note the aiml package only works with Python 2. Py3kAiml on GitHub is a Python 3 alternative. You also refer to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33971568/6521116).

Comment: you can use python --version to check the default python version, may be you've also installed python3.

Comment: Yes Kris i have checked.. am using 2.7

Comment: aiml.Kernel(), uppercase the K

Comment: Thank You kris it is working... May i know the reason for that uppercase "K"

Comment: @kumararaja python is a case sensitive language. So the funciton Kernel() and kernel() are not the same. Only Kernel() is defind in the module aiml

Answer (score 0):

run `pip install python-aiml`
**not** `pip install aiml`

Comment: .. how do you think package reinstall helps fixing a typo? (v0.9.2 >> 0.9.3). The question is three years old so they may have implemented a pointer for capitals thereafter whatever version OP was on at the time of posting question.

Comment: it fixed my issue, my result of research - that is what i provided, he may find that helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

You Need to downloading the `pip install python-aiml` package for this issue.Don't change your Version of your Python.